# Rigorous introduction to statistics for self study

Tags: statistics, reference-request, soft-question, self-learning, book-recommendation

I want to start learning statistics.
I have taken proof-based Calculus 1 and 2, as well as two proof-based courses in Linear Algebra (1 and 2). What is a good introductory-level (but rigorous enough) book to start self-learning statistics? Also, if you know about any other resources (other than books) to help my self study, you can recommend them. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a whole free online book + other resources (https://www.probabilitycourse.com/) based on a course taught at UMass Amherst. It is rigorous enough without going into measure theory.